# Retrieve and Display image from database not displaying image in proper format

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woo-commerce plugin.I have customized plugin to add the product from front end,Its working fine and I have added product to the database successfully, now i have to display that product image into the class="product-thumbn as my product bellow is my code I am not getting any idea how to do this.

```
<td class="product-thumbnail" >
            <?php
              global $wpdb;
           $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM user_templates  where id= '14' " );

             foreach ( $result as $print )  
           echo $print->BgImageName;

         echo '<img src="/user_templates/'.$print->BgImageName.'"/>';
                                       ?>
             </td>
```

I am getting a bellow output here I am getting only image name not an image.

[image]

Comment: First of do you do a SQL Query just for the image name? If so please change the * to just BgImageName. Also could you show us the html output? From your code I gather that you'd expect the output code to be "<img src="/user_templates/BgImageName.png"/>" but it is rather hard to know what is going on just by looking at the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Got the right answer...

```
<td class="product-thumbnail" >
                <?php
    global $wpdb;
     $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM user_templates  where id= ".$_SESSION['user_te']);
    foreach ( $result as $print )  
    $img_post=$print->BgImageName;
     // echo '<img src="src="../user_templates/'//.$print->BgImageName.'"/>';
        ?>                                                   
     <image height="100"src="../user_templates/<?php echo $img_post;?>" />

      </td>
```